# XSL: Remove namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, prefix

After searching for a while i figured I'd ask here. I'm trying to remove the empty namespace from an XSL output file. Let me provide the relevant code:

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier xmlns="un:unece:260:data:EEM-DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier:v2">
    <HeaderEnergyDocument>
        <Creation>Date</Creation>
    </HeaderEnergyDocument>
</DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ns1="un:unece:260:data:EEM-DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier:v2"
            exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="ns1:DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier">
            <McsDkSMBMsg 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateElement">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ElementName" select="'Creation'" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </McsDkSMBMsg>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="CreateElement">
        <xsl:param name="ElementName"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:element name="{$ElementName}">Testing</xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<McsDkSMBMsg xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg">
    <Creation xmlns="">Testing</Creation>
</McsDkSMBMsg>
```

How do I remove the namespace? Am I doing something completely wrong XSL-wise? I'm slowly pulling my hair out. Regards.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you working with? I cannot reproduce your issue with Saxon or Xalan.

Comment: The XSL was incorrect and has been edited. You should be able to reproduce it now.

Comment: The simplest fix would be to move the `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg"` declaration onto the top-level `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: "Thank God this XML has namespaces in it" said by NO ONE EVER...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code adds two elements to the output tree: One called `McsDkSMBMsg` which has a *default namespace*:

```
<McsDkSMBMsg xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg">
```

the other one is `Creation` - which, according to your original code, is in *no namespace* at all. The only way for the XSLT processor to ensure that the `Creation` element does not end up in the default namespace is to *undeclare* this namespace:

```
<Creation xmlns="">Testing</Creation>
```

I assume you'd like the `Creation` element to also belong to that default namespace. If so, simply add the same `xmlns` attribute to the `xsl:element` instruction where `Creation` is created. The XLST processor will take care of any redundant namespace declarations.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ns1="un:unece:260:data:EEM-DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier:v2"
            exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="ns1:DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier">
            <McsDkSMBMsg 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateElement">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ElementName" select="'Creation'" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </McsDkSMBMsg>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="CreateElement">
        <xsl:param name="ElementName"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:element name="{$ElementName}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg">Testing</xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

Now an `xmlns` attribute is only present on the `McsDkSMBMsg` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<McsDkSMBMsg xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg">
   <Creation>Testing</Creation>
</McsDkSMBMsg>
```

---

That said, perhaps your code could need some improvement. You are applying a `for-each` to the outermost element - of which there can only be one - which makes no sense. Also, it might be more reasonable to define a *prefix* for the new namespace. And you are calling a named template for no obvious reason.

The usefulness of it depends on the actual XML input and on other code you already have.

**Improved Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ns1="un:unece:260:data:EEM-DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier:v2"
            xmlns:msg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/McsDkSMBMsg"
            exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:DK_RequestChangeOfSupplier">
            <msg:McsDkSMBMsg>
                <xsl:element name="msg:Creation">Testing</xsl:element>
            </msg:McsDkSMBMsg>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Haha. That was brilliant. Guess I have to go back to the basics of XSL and namespaces. Thank you!

Comment: @user2980567 You are welcome. Please also have a look at the improvements I suggest - perhaps they are useful?

Comment: They are indeed useful. My original XSL doc and Input XML contains somewhat more data than described and I also have to maintain some strict standards. I will definitely look into it. Thank you.